# Add Dependencies to Maven from Custom Eclipse Version (Repast)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, classpath

I'm currently working on a simulation project, using Repast. It's a custom eclipse version that comes with inbuilt libraries for the actual simulation.

I now want to make a maven-project out of this. However, I cannot figure out, how to include the Repast-libraries to my pom.xml, since there's neither an entry on the mvnrepository, nor are the libraries included in my project folder. They all come from the repast plugin and reside inside my eclipse installation, as you can see below:

[Package Explorer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogMAm.png)

This is how my pom.xml looks like right now:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Simulation</groupId>
  <artifactId>Simulation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Simulation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>simulation.app.UserMain</mainClass>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> 
            <phase>package</phase> 
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- some other dependencies that are required -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The corresponding entry in my classpath is this:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="REPAST_SIMPHONY_SUPPORT"/>
```

But how do I put this into my maven-project?
Whenever I run the maven build process, the resulting JAR terminates with "NoClassDefFoundErrors". When I open the JAR-File with WinRaR, I see that the repast libraries are not in there.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quick google search found this: https://sourceforge.net/p/repast/mailman/message/34207780/

Comment: yeah, I know that post. But that's the other way around. He's asking, how to get the maven-dependencies into the repast launchers, not the repast-libraries into the maven build.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused when there is a class file that your code depends on and it is present at compile time but not found at runtime. Look for differences in your build time and runtime classpaths.

you can refer this link : 
https://dzone.com/articles/how-resolve-0

https://dzone.com/articles/how-resolve-1

Answer (score 0):

As referenced in this [SourceForge forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/repast/mailman/message/34207780/):

> The jars contained in the Eclipse Maven Managed Dependencies are not
>   included in the classpath used by the default launcher associated with a
>   Repast project. Because of this, launching the project when there are Maven
>   dependencies will result in a NoClassDefFoundError as Repast searches
>   through the classpath looking for annotations.

The solution is as follows:

Add the Eclipse Maven Managed
Dependencies to the launch file (located in launchers/[project name]
Model.launch). Add the following line to the classpath entries:

```
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;
encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;
standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry
containerPath=&quot;org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER&quot;
path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;4&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
```

Comment: yeah, I know that post. But that's the other way around. He's asking, how to get the maven-dependencies into the repast launchers, not the repast-libraries into the maven build